# Regex Search specific words before period

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using Regex to search specific words

```
var item = "If ";
string str = "If .DataFound Then";

Regex regex = new Regex("\\b"+ item + "\\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   
var count = regex.Matches(str).Count;
```

count return 0.
expected result is 1.

"If " with space is intended.
standard string is ok, but if we have period just like above example, it doesn't count.

Comment: Please try this: `\bIf\b\s` ; `"\\b"+ item + "\\b\\s"`

Comment: @MarkusMeyer it's not working. it's space meet period that doesn't working